# get /dev/random in kernel module

Tags: random, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I need to get both `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` within kernel module.

`get_random_bytes` API provided to get `/dev/urandom`.

But there is no API for `/dev/random` so I tried to ioctl and read file in kernel space.
Here is what I have done.

1. using `RNDGETPOOL` ioctl

in `include/linux/random.h`
`RNDGETPOOL` is declared

```
/* Get the contents of the entropy pool.  (Superuser only.) */
#define RNDGETPOOL      _IOR( 'R', 0x02, int [2] )
```

but, It won't work so I checked `driver/char/random.h` noticed `RNDGETPOOL` is gone!!

```
static long random_ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    int size, ent_count;
    int __user *p = (int __user *)arg;
    int retval;

    switch (cmd) {
    case RNDGETENTCNT:
            /* inherently racy, no point locking */
            if (put_user(input_pool.entropy_count, p))
                    return -EFAULT;
            return 0;
    case RNDADDTOENTCNT:
            if (!capable(CAP_SYS_ADMIN))
                    return -EPERM;
            if (get_user(ent_count, p))
                    return -EFAULT;
            credit_entropy_bits(&input_pool, ent_count);
            return 0;
    case RNDADDENTROPY:
            if (!capable(CAP_SYS_ADMIN))
                    return -EPERM;
            if (get_user(ent_count, p++))
                    return -EFAULT;
            if (ent_count < 0)
                    return -EINVAL;
            if (get_user(size, p++))
                    return -EFAULT;
            retval = write_pool(&input_pool, (const char __user *)p,
                                size);
            if (retval < 0)
                    return retval;
            credit_entropy_bits(&input_pool, ent_count);
            return 0;
    case RNDZAPENTCNT:
    case RNDCLEARPOOL:
            /* Clear the entropy pool counters. */
            if (!capable(CAP_SYS_ADMIN))
                    return -EPERM;
            rand_initialize();
            return 0;
    default:
            return -EINVAL;
    }
}
```

I searched [google](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwi00cexvr_NAhWBPJQKHX_fALAQFggoMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yqcomputer.com%2F1272_1258_1.htm&usg=AFQjCNHBCXsx1CFNEXkQOf5ihvuH4qlg2w&bvm=bv.125596728,d.dGo) and find out ioctl `RNDGETPOOL` is removed. done!

2. using `random_read` function from `driver/char/random.c:997`

   ```
   static ssize_t random_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t nbytes, loff_t *ppos)
   ```

here is my kernel module's function accesses to `/dev/random`.

```
static void read_file()
{
  struct file *file;
  loff_t pos = 0;
  //ssize_t wc;
  unsigned char buf_ent[21]={0,};
  int ent_c;
  int i;
  ssize_t length = 0;

  mm_segment_t old_fs = get_fs();
  set_fs(KERNEL_DS);

  file = filp_open("/dev/random", O_WRONLY, 0);
  file->f_op->unlocked_ioctl(file, RNDGETENTCNT, &ent_c);
  if(ent_c < sizeof(char))
  {
    printk("not enough entropy\n");
  }
  printk("ent counter : %d\n", ent_c);

  //file->f_op->unlocked_ioctl(file, RNDGETPOOL, &ent_st.buf);
  length = file->f_op->read(file, buf_ent, ent_c/ 8, &pos);
  if(length <0)
  {
    printk("failed to random_read\n");
  }
  printk("length : %d\n", length);
  printk("ent: ");
  for(i=0;i<length; i++)
  {
      printk("%02x", buf_ent[i]);
  }
  printk("\n");
  filp_close(file,0);
  set_fs(old_fs);
}
```

outputs seems to be random

first try

```
[1290902.992048] ent_c : 165  
[1290902.992060] length : 20  
[1290902.992060] ent: d89290f4a5eea8e087a63943ed0129041e80b568
```

second try

```
[1290911.493990] ent_c : 33  
[1290911.493994] length : 4  
[1290911.493994] ent: 7832640a
```

by the way `random_read` function argument has `__user` keyword. Buf `buf` in code is in kernel space.

Is appropriate using `random_read` function in kernel space??

Comment: *outputs seems to be random* — https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Why do you think you need bits from *both* pools?

Answer (score 3):

The in-kernel interface to get random bytes is `get_random_bytes()`:

```c
static void read_file(void)
{
    unsigned char buf_ent[21];

    get_random_bytes(buf_ent, 21);
    print_hex_dump_bytes("ent: ", DUMP_PREFIX_NONE, buf_ent, 21);
}
```

Comment: yes, there is get_random_bytes functions for /dev/urandom, but I am hoping to read /dev/random.